# Javascript trigger without button click

Tags: javascript

i have some problems here..
I have an input that should be multplied by 3 without button

This is my code

```
    <input type="number" placeholder="Input a number" id="number"
     onclick="multiply()">

    <div id="result"></div>
```

This is my script

```
    <script>
       function multiply(){
          var num = document.getElementById('number').value;
          var res = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML;

          res = num * 3;

       }
    </script>
```

So here i want user can input the number and get the result immediatelly without button..

Thanks..

(Beginner Programmer)

Comment: I don't get it. You didn't say how you're trying to trigger it otherwise.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the input to calculate an answer every time there is a change?

Comment: `res = num * 3;` - that updates the var `res` - it does not update `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML`

Comment: Yes, i want that every time the input change, the result will calculate automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the inline `onclick` handler and subscribe to the `input` event instead;

```
var res = document.getElementById('result');

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('input', function() {
    res.textContent = this.value * 3;
}, false);
```

```js
var res = document.getElementById('result');

document.getElementById('number').addEventListener('input', function() {
  res.innerHTML = this.value * 3;
}, false);
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="Input a number" id="number">

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `innerHTML`? >:( Unparsed string as number?! >:(

Comment: It doesn't matter when multiplying

Comment: That's true, though if it's not a number of course it'll be `NaN`

Comment: @SterlingArcher - it would, but as the OP is **multiplying** I assumed it was a number *(and the input is of type `number`)*. Also, what's wrong with `innerHTML` ?

Comment: It's bad practice to use `innerHTML` when you're not manipulating HTML. `textContent` should be used here. I'm a bit of a stickler Meeseeks.

Comment: @SterlingArcher  - okay, I'll agree with you on that one, as a principle inserting text doesn't need `innerHTML`.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Except `textContent` is more hassle for those of us who still have to (occasionally) support IE8.

Comment: @nnnnnn - true, it's good to no longer have to do the old `innerText || textContent` hacks.

Comment: Good practice doesn't take into account legacy support :D

Comment: Thanks, it really works.. but, is that really works too in alphabetical / text input??

Comment: @LuthHizb the input is restricted to numbers.

Comment: @LuthHizb - it works as long as you input a number, which is what one would expect in an input for numbers only, For regular text, it probably doesn't work, as `"a" * 3` makes little sense and ends up being `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`onChange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) function.

> The onchange event occurs when the value of an element has been changed.
>
> For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the onchange event occurs when the checked state has been changed.
>
> — w3schools

For example

```
document.querySelector("#number").addEventListener("change", function () {
      var num = document.querySelector("#number").value;
      document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML;

      document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = num * 3;
});
```